# React ChartJS prevent new data from being added into state after it's redrawn?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs, react-state-management

I'm trying to update my chart using react-chartjs-2. I'm using date picker to filter different data and re-render the chart accordingly such as display data today, yesterday, last 7 days etc.. The data is being fetched from my database

However, when the chart gets redrawn, and re-rendered, it gets added onto the state which I don't want. I simply want to re-render the new data that was requested **not** re-render and add onto the old data that was in the chart.

I actually fixed this issue before with vanilla JavaScript because I wasn't using react I used the `destroy()` method that the chart documentation says to use but i'm not sure how to use it with react?

So upon further inspection, it seems my chart is re-rendering fine. However, when it gets re-rendered, additional data is being added onto my chartData state which I don't want, I just want the new data that got requested to show on the chart. I'm still trying to figure that portion out.

Here is my code I have a lot of it so I'll only show the relevant parts:

```js
import React from "react";

import reportsService from "../../services/reportsService";
import update from "react-addons-update";
import moment from "moment";

import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";
import "chartjs-plugin-labels";
import "chartjs-plugin-datalabels";

class Reportspage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      chartData: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [
          {
            //label: "Quotes",
            data: [],
            backgroundColor: []
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  }

  chartColors() {
    let colors = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200);
      let g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200);
      let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200);
      let c = "rgb(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";
      colors.push(c);
    }

    // Update deep nested array of objects in state
    this.setState({
      chartData: update(this.state.chartData, {
        datasets: { 0: { backgroundColor: { $set: colors } } }
      })
    });
  }

  datePicker() {
    let _this = this;
    let start = moment().subtract(29, "days");
    let end = moment();
    let showReports;
    let data;
    let reloNames = [];
    let reloCount = [];

    function focusDate(start, end) {
      $("#daterangePicker span").html(
        start.format("MMMM D, YYYY") + " - " + end.format("MMMM D, YYYY")
      );
    }

    $("#daterangePicker").daterangepicker(
      {
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        ranges: {
          Today: [moment(), moment()],
          Yesterday: [
            moment().subtract(1, "days"),
            moment().subtract(1, "days")
          ],
          "Last 7 Days": [moment().subtract(6, "days"), moment()],
          "Last 30 Days": [moment().subtract(29, "days"), moment()],
          "This Month": [moment().startOf("month"), moment().endOf("month")],
          "Last Month": [
            moment()
              .subtract(1, "month")
              .startOf("month"),
            moment()
              .subtract(1, "month")
              .endOf("month")
          ]
        }
      },
      focusDate
    );

    focusDate(start, end);

    $("#daterangePicker").on("apply.daterangepicker", async function(
      event,
      picker
    ) {
      switch (picker.chosenLabel) {
        case "Today":
          showReports = await reportsService.reloQuotes({
            reportStatus: "Today"
          });

          data = showReports.recordsets[0];

          data.forEach((element, index, array) => {
            reloNames.push(element.reloNames);
            reloCount.push(element.NoofOrders);
          });

          _this.setState({
            chartData: update(_this.state.chartData, {
              labels: { $set: reloNames },
              datasets: { 0: { data: { $set: reloCount } } }
            })
          });

          console.log(_this.state);

          break;
        case "Yesterday":
          showReports = await reportsService.reloQuotes({
            reportStatus: "Yesterday"
          });

          data = showReports.recordsets[0];

          data.forEach((element, index, array) => {
            reloNames.push(element.reloNames);
            reloCount.push(element.NoofOrders);
          });

          _this.setState({
            chartData: update(_this.state.chartData, {
              labels: { $set: reloNames },
              datasets: { 0: { data: { $set: reloCount } } }
            })
          });

          console.log(_this.state);

          break;
        case "Last 7 Days":
          showReports = await reportsService.reloQuotes({
            reportStatus: "Last 7 Days"
          });

          data = showReports.recordsets[0];

          data.forEach((element, index, array) => {
            reloNames.push(element.reloNames);
            reloCount.push(element.NoofOrders);
          });

          _this.setState({
            chartData: update(_this.state.chartData, {
              labels: { $set: reloNames },
              datasets: { 0: { data: { $set: reloCount } } }
            })
          });

          console.log(_this.state);

          break;
      }
    });

    //console.log(this.state);
  }

  async reloQuotes() {
    const showreloQuotes = await reportsService.reloQuotes();
    let data = showreloQuotes.recordsets[0];
    let reloNames = [];
    let reloCount = [];

    data.forEach((element, index, array) => {
      reloNames.push(element.reloNames);
      reloCount.push(element.NoofOrders);
    });

    this.setState({
      chartData: update(this.state.chartData, {
        labels: { $set: reloNames },
        datasets: { 0: { data: { $set: reloCount } } }
      })
    });
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.chartColors();
    await this.datePicker();

    // Execute models real time thus re-rendering live data on the chart real time
    await this.reloQuotes();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="fluid-container">
        <div className="container">
          <h1>Reports</h1>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="daterangeContainer">
              <div
                id="daterangePicker"
                style={{
                  background: "#fff",
                  cursor: "pointer",
                  padding: "5px 10px",
                  border: "1px solid #ccc",
                  width: "100%"
                }}
              >
                <i className="fa fa-calendar" />
                &nbsp;
                <span /> <i className="fa fa-caret-down" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-12">
              <Bar
                data={this.state.chartData}
                height={800}
                options={{
                  maintainAspectRatio: false,
                  legend: {
                    display: false
                  },
                  scales: {
                    xAxes: [
                      {
                        ticks: {
                          beginAtZero: true,
                          autoSkip: false
                        },
                        scaleLabel: {
                          display: true
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: "Quotes",
                    fontSize: 16
                  },
                  plugins: {
                    datalabels: {
                      display: true,
                      color: "white"
                    }
                  }
                }}
                redraw
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Reportspage;
```

Answer (score 2):

So the problem that you describe is that data is added to your component state when the component is re-rendered. In the code snipped you have supplied, you dont use any of the life cycle methods in React that can be triggered on re-renders. And I cannot see any other hooks that should trigger on a re-render. Therefore I cant find any source to your problem.

However, I can see other issues that might make debugging harder for you. Solving these might help you in nailing down the actual problem. In the `componentDidMount` method you call functions whose only purpose is to update the state. This is not good design since it will force the component to immediately re-render several times whenever it is mounted.

A better design is to fully prepare the chartData-objekt in the constructor. For example, you could change your `chartColors` function to take a chartData object as a parameter, and return the new object with colors added. Then make your constructor look something like this:

```
constructor(props) {

   super(props);
   const chartDataWithoutColors = {
       labels: [],
       datasets: [
         {
           //label: "Quotes",
           data: [],
           backgroundColor: []
         }
       ]
     }

   const chartDataWithColor = this.chartColors(chartDataWithoutColors);

   this.state = {
     chartData: chartDataWithColor
   };
}
```

By removing unnecessary calls to `setState` you will make your components life both simpler and more performant. When you have simplified your component, start debugging by removing non-critical parts one at the time and try to nail down when your problem disappears. This should be sufficient to find the bug.

Good luck!

Comment: Okay I'll try using the different life cycles instead of setting state immediately on mounting on the component. thank you I'll try a different approach and get back to you on this.

Comment: So I think I need to do more research on my problem in order to fix the issue I'm having. What I'm going to try is completely removing all the code I have now and try a different approach to this. I'm not sure how to end this bounty but I'll just see if I can try a different approach. Thank you for your suggestion I'll use it in the future.